# Limit of sequence using Euler's sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)^n$

I know that this approaches $e^{1/2}$ however don't know how to prove this. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The way you have types the expression the limit is $1$. I believe you wanted the n-th power outside  $()$.

Comment: Do you know that $(1+(1/n))^n\to e$? If so then this implies that $(1+(1/(2n+3)))^{2n+3}\to e$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)^{2n+3}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)^{n}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)^{3}$.

Comment: Simple and clear. +1

Comment: @ Paramanand: thanks !

Comment: Very ingenious!  +1

Answer (score 1):

Simply put 
$$
2n+3=m\iff n=\frac{m -3}{2}
$$
Now we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)^n= \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{\frac{m -3}{2}}
$$
and applying the usual rules of calculation of limits you get the sought for result.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1{an+b}\right)^n=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1{an+b}\right)^{an+b}\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{an+b}}$$